# Insert into Select using JPA

Tags: java, sql, database, jpa

I am using JPA (with Hibernate) to talk to the database. I have a task of selecting all records from Table1 and insert into Table2. Can I achieve this using JPA in one step?

I tried using @Query annotation and provided a HQL query `(INSERT INTO TABLE1.. SELECT * FROM TABLE2)` to it but got a DML error.

**Note:** As a last resort I am doing it in two steps now, which seems to be inefficient:

step1: getAll from table1

step2: save to table2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPA tries to do some O/R-Mapping for you.

Your request is just moving data between two relational tables (or a table and pseudo-table). So why do you need to use JPA to do that? Just go straight and use JDBC, or native query. And never forget that nothing is a silver bullet especially an O/RM.